# Hiding an element on a page with GTM

Tags: html

I am using AddThis in Google Tag Manager as below

```
<!-- Go to www.addthis.com/dashboard to customize your tools -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-7HYYROFT55eaab" async="async">

</script>
```

I have a h2 element on the page above the AddThis tag

```
<h2 id ="Share">Share</h2>
```

When a blocking trigger is applied to the AddThis tag is it possible to hide this element